# \thanks creates an empty first page

Tags: footnotes, titles, article

## Problem

As I am using the `\thanks` for the `\maketitle` command, the `\thanks` creates an empty first page, with only a footnote reference number 1 in it.

I am using maxTeX XeLaTeX to compile.

## Code

```
\documentclass[a4,12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\author{Chenlin \\ l.wind.wang@gmail.com}
\date{2013.12.21}
\thanks{This is a test!}

\title{A Experiment on \LaTeX \\ The Maketitle Experiement}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try putting `\thanks` inside either `\title` or `\author`

Comment: @Archimedes520 Note that the option name is `a4paper` and not `a4`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`\thanks` puts footnotes in the title page, which is created by `\maketitle`. In the `article` document class, `\maketitle` processes `\title`, `\author`, and `\date`. So any footnote added to the title page must be given within the scope of either of these three commands.

## Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\author{Chenlin\thanks{notes on author} \\ l.wind.wang@gmail.com\thanks{This is a test!}}
\date{2013.12.21\thanks{notes on date}}

\title{A Experiment on \LaTeX \\ The Maketitle Experiement\thanks{notes on title}}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]